# How to sum up the data of the category in a box-plot using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a set of data that are under different categories and I would like to sum up the value under the same type (operating and development) and display using type using box plot via seaborn.

I have tried to use groupby() but got this error message: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.

```
import seaborn as sns 
from matplotlib import  axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expenditure_df = pd.read_csv("Expenditure.csv")
expenditure_df.head()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))

grouped_data = expenditure_df.groupby(['category'])
sum_values = grouped_data['Utilities', 'Rental', 'Salary'].sum()

df1 = expenditure_df[expenditure_df['type'].isin(['Operating','Development'])]
df1.head()

sns.boxplot(y='amount', x='year', 
                 data=df1, 
                 palette="colorblind",
                 hue='type')

ax = sns.countplot(x="year", data=df1)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is my sample data.
[image: sample data]

Comment: Can you describe a little clearer the current issue? How is the current plot specifically returning undesired results? On a quick read it seems to address your opening sentence: _sum up the value and display using type_.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the summary over all the years, it to append a copy of the dataframe, but changing the value in the year column.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some dummy data
np.random.seed(31415)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.repeat(np.arange(2010, 2023), 100)})
df1['type'] = np.random.choice(['Operating', 'Development'], len(df1))
df1['amount'] = np.random.randint(-19, 21, len(df1)).cumsum() + 1000

# copy the dataframe and change the 'year' column
df2 = df1.copy()
df2['year'] = 'overall'
# concatenate both dataframes
df_combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
sns.boxplot(y='amount', x='year',
            data=df_combined,
            palette="colorblind",
            hue='type', ax=ax)
ax.axvline(len(df1['year'].unique()) - 0.5, ls=':', color='blue')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=40)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with overall summary]

If you want to sum up the amounts per type per year, you can draw a `sns.barplot()` with `estimator=sum`. (`errorbar=None` is needed to suppress the errorbar which doesn't make sense in this case). A box plot wouldn't work with only one amount per box.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
sns.barplot(data=df1, x='year', y='amount', hue='type',
            palette="colorblind", estimator=sum, errorbar=None, ax=ax)
```

[image: sns.barplot of sums]

PS: instead of using `expenditure_df[expenditure_df['type'].isin(['Operating','Development'])]`, with seaborn you can take a subset of the hue values with `hue_order`, like `sns.barplot(data=expenditure_df, x=..., y=..., hue='type', hue_order='Operating','Development'], ...)`.

Comment: Hi @JohanC, thanks for helping.  Is it possible to sum up the data by year so that I can do year by year analysis instead of overall.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the same plot without `hue`? I.e. `sns.boxplot(y='amount', x='year', data=df1, palette="colorblind")`? That would put together the values per year, independent of `'type'`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. as per the sample data set, there are few categories under each type. how can i sum  up all the amount under the categories that belong to operating or development?

Comment: I edited the answer to add how you can show sums.

Comment: If this answer was useful, you might consider upvoting. If your question is solved now, you might consider marking the answer as accepted.